# PyWin32 handler registered by PyCWnd.HookMessage() not being called after PyCWnd.PostMessage() and PumpWaitingMessages()

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I'm creating an windows app using `pywin32`, specifically with components under `pywin.mfc` module.

For internal logic, I want the app to do certain things whenever a user defined window message is posted by [`PyCWnd.PostMessage()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyCWnd__PostMessage_meth.html) function.
So I registered an handler method using [`PyCWnd.HookMessage()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyCWnd__HookMessage_meth.html) but that never gets triggered although I do `PyCWnd.PostMessage()`.

My vague guess is that the message pump implementation that I'm using is not suitable for `Pythonwin` framework compared to win32 apis, but not sure.

Python script below is used for testing.

The `PumpWaitingMessages()` implementation below is copied from builtin method [`win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/7d5c7277900cd8fa5c3fb0ffa118fa5c8dc75de5/win32/src/win32gui.i#L3393-L3425) but written in python in order to inspect what is going on inside that function.
You can just replace with the original one if it's suspicious.

I expect app prints "OnUser" asynchronously after calling `frame.PostMessage(win32con.WM_USER, 0, 0)`.

```py
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ui

from pywin.mfc.thread import WinApp
from pywin.mfc.window import MDIFrameWnd

app = WinApp()
frame = MDIFrameWnd()
app.SetMainFrame(frame)
frame.LoadFrame(
    win32ui.IDR_MAINFRAME,
    win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
)
frame.UpdateWindow()


def OnUser(params):
    print("OnUser")


frame.HookMessage(OnUser, win32con.WM_USER)  # let's print "OnUser" on WM_USER message
frame.SendMessage(win32con.WM_USER, 0, 0)  # prints "OnUser" right away
frame.PostMessage(win32con.WM_USER, 0, 0)  # hope that app prints "OnUser" later on


def PumpWaitingMessages():
    available = 1
    should_quit = 0
    while available:
        available, msg = win32gui.PeekMessage(0, 0, 0, win32con.PM_REMOVE)
        if available:
            if msg[1] == win32con.WM_QUIT:
                should_quit = 1
                break
            win32gui.TranslateMessage(msg)
            print(msg)  # seems the posted message reaches here
            win32gui.DispatchMessage(msg)  # but dispatch does nothing on that message
    return should_quit


while not PumpWaitingMessages():
    pass
```

Comment: Have you tried to call frame.UpdateWindow()? I guess this shall trigger the event loop.